# fpdf not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, fpdf, email

I have a form in a wordpress plugin which sends an email to the client when admin allots him some points,but I also want to create a pdf document and attach it to the email and send it to client, I have used fpdf for this but the code doesn't even sends an email now, This is my code

```
$to = $clientName;
$from = "wordpress@electronicsguide.000webhostapp.com";
$message =  $positive_email_body;

    $pdf=new FPDF('P', 'pt', array(500, 233));
    $pdf->AddFont('Georgiai', '', 'georgiai.php');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('georgiai', '', 16);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'This is a pdf example');
    $separator = md5(time());
    $eol = PHP_EOL;
    $filename = "invoice.pdf";
    $pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("invoice", "S");
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));
    $headers = "From: ".$from.$eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
    $body = "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
    $body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;
    $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
    $body .= $message.$eol;
    $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
    $body .= $attachment.$eol;
    $body .= "--".$separator."--";
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Please help